# How to display a specific value from an API call in a simple html page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have very basic knowledge of HTML and almost no knowledge of javascript or jquery etc. Most answers on SO are referring to those so I am posting this question in hope someone can guide me. I have worked with APIs with languages like R and python but was looking for a lightweight solution. I have an static API url which returns a json object.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY

I want a very barebones html page which when opened gets the data and displays one of the fields  in the json object. In this case duration:text. I can refresh the page each time I want the latest value but an auto refreshing page every x seconds would be extra awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = setInterval(()=>fetch("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20rows.elements.duration.text%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fmaps.googleapis.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fdistancematrix%2Fjson%3Funits%3Dimperial%26origins%3DWashington%2CDC%26destinations%3DNew%2BYork%2BCity%2CNY'&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
.then(r=>r.json()).then(b=>console.log(b.query.results.json.rows.elements.duration.text)),2000);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

How does this look to you?

Comment: I really should learn more JS. That almost seems like magic. I get what the first part is doing. But what is the purpose of the 2nd part and what is the yahoo api doing in there. Basically this does answer my question but now I have more questions :)

Comment: @Rohit Essentially, this uses the recent Promise and fetch systems to grab data using Yahoo Query Language, then convert to JSON, display the data point, and repeat every 2000 ms.